# .Net Core -> How to decrypt using a 1024bit key

Tags: c#, .net-core, cryptography, rsa

How can i decrypt a RSA message using a 1024bit key? [It looks like only 512bits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsaencryptionpadding?view=netcore-2.2) are enabled by default options

Comment: The page you linked talks about the padding. Have a look at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa?view=netcore-2.2)

Comment: the thing is that, in order to decrypt, i must inform a padding... right?

Comment: Yes, if applied. Do you know all the parameters?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are referring to the maximum bit size for the hash function for MGF1 used within the OAEP padding. That size does limit the amount of data that can be encrypted, but only because the padding requires a certain amount of overhead. So the hash size does help determine the amount of overhead. So in a sense it does determine the *minimum* key size required. To check the overhead incurred by OAEP with a specific hash have a look at my answer [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/42100/1172). So with SHA-512 you actually *require* a key size larger than 1024 bits as the overhead alone is 130 bytes (1040 bits).

RSA keys of 1024 bits are considered to provide a very low amount of security. With those kind of keys it is likely that an older scheme called PKCS#1 v1.5 padding is applied. This one is the `Pkcs1` option displayed on the page [that you referenced in the question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsaencryptionpadding?view=netcore-2.2). This one requires an overhead of only 11 bytes / 88 bits, so it can be used with any practical key size. The protocol should define which one of the options you actually need (so if you don't know: ask the other party).

---

To get the actual key size that is supported you should have a look at [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> The `RSACryptoServiceProvider` supports key sizes from 384 bits to 16384 bits in increments of 8 bits if you have the Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider installed. It supports key sizes from 384 bits to 512 bits in increments of 8 bits if you have the Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider installed.
>
> Valid key sizes are dependent on the cryptographic service provider (CSP) that is used by the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` instance. Windows CSPs enable keys sizes of 384 to 16384 bits for Windows versions prior to Windows 8.1, and key sizes of 512 to 16384 bits for Windows 8.1. For more information, see `CryptGenKey` function in the Windows documentation.

Note that you only require 16 to 32 bytes of payload in the RSA encryption to encrypt a limitless amount of data. This is because you can use the 16 or 32 bytes to encrypt an 128 or 256 bit AES key. This key can then be used to encrypt the plaintext itself, e.g. using AES in GCM mode to be secure. This kind of scheme is called a "hybrid cryptosystem".

---

That later remark is important if you are using a hardware provider like a smart card. Not many hardware providers will suppose 16Ki bit keys. First of all, they commonly don't have the hardware to accommodate modular exponentiation of such large values. Secondly, generating a 16Ki bit RSA key pair can take a very long time, especially on devices with limited hardware (it depends on finding two random 8Ki bit primes, after all).

Many smart cards only have pre-generated key pairs of a specific size so you cannot even generate new ones; you can only use the private key with the pre-configured size.

Comment: It took me 5 links to find the key size requirements by the way - and a scroll past the example code, and I knew what I was looking for. In other words, I'm not surprised if this kind of info is kind of hard to find.

Comment: Anything missing from my answer, Leonardo? It's hard enough getting any kind of reputation from answering cryptographic based questions as it is. You may want to upvote some more answers you are getting as well.